# radix sort base condition?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement radix sort that sorts 50000 integers using a queue.

I have two idea in my mind for the base condition and I'm not sure it will work.

1. Get the biggest value in the array to determine how many times we need to go through the 10th, 100th, 1000th space.
2. Put number in the appropriate bin queue until all numbers have 0 at the front then return the integer in the bin back to the array?

Please let me know if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this : www.math.ucla.edu/~tat/MicroTeach/radixsort.ppt

Comment: pos=( (d==1)? tmp%10: tmp/10 ); what does this do shown in the powerpoint? i dont really understand c++.

Comment: if (d==1) pos = tmp%10 else tmp/10